# JS window.close popup isn't working after refresh of parent

Tags: javascript, php, html, popupwindow, page-refresh

Currently i'm creating a simple html/php/js project for internal use and found a little problem i can't solve by my self :-(

In my parent window is a JS function which opens and closes a popup with:

```
function openit(){
  boersenfenster = window.open('boerse.php','_blank','scrollbars=no');
}
function closeit(){
  boersenfenster.close();
}
```

Now after a while the parent window refreshes to get fresh data of a csv file and after the page reload the closeit() function isn't working anymore. In my thoughts, the parent window can't remember the openend popup after the refresh but how can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe the parent window has lost the the link, so you can either
use ajax to update your page, or close the child window like this

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload',function(e){
       boersenfenster.close();
};
```

and then reopen the child window after the page has reloaded

Comment: thanks for the answer, so reopen the child window is not really an option because it's showed fullscreen on a beamer in a show.

I haven't worked with ajax yet, is there a easy way to implement what i need?

Comment: so you can either use ajax to update the page, or possibly use local storage.http://www.codediesel.com/javascript/sharing-messages-and-data-across-windows-using-localstorage/